# Comparing two numbers

Tags: numbers

I am wondering how can I express that A is greater than B for some number. For example, can I say "5 is greater than 3 for 2", or should I say "5 is 2 greater than 3"? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

Of your two examples, only "5 is 2 greater than 3" is correct.  The other option that would work similar to your first example is "5 is greater than 3 *by* 2".

Answer (score 0):

You can say "five is greater than three by two" or "five is 2 (units) greater than 3" but not "five is greater than 3 for 2".

Answer (score 0):

All you said are correct, except "for" usage. You just have to replace "for" by "by".
Good Luck.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @aediaλ in what way doesn't this answer the question?  He's correct that in the two examples if you just replace the word 'for' with 'by', it's correct.  It's certainly not critiquing or requesting clarification.

Comment: "Good brevity makes sense". aedia.. No need for long clarification for just prepositions replacement..The conclusion would be lost if I had formulated many diversified statements.
 Thanks Dusty, you've clarified what aedia couldn't understand.